# How to group in linq list and concatenate some string in c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a domain entity called "HoldItems" and i created a list of HoldItems object.

All the attribute on that HoldItems are:

```
public int TransactionNo;
public int TransactionID;
public int ItemNo;
public String ItemName;
public int Qty;
public double Price;
public double TotalPrice;
public double DiscountPrice;
public int ItemType;
public bool VatInclude;
public double VatPrice;
public string Note;
public List<HoldExtraMenu> ExtraMenuList;
public string BelongCategoryName;
public int BelongItemNo;
public int BelongItemIndex;
public int BelongCategoryID;
```

I wrote some LINQ query like this, that selectedItemList represent `List<DomainEntities.HoldItems>`

```
var results = from myobject in selectedItemList
              where myobject.ItemType == 5
              where myobject.BelongItemIndex==selectedItemList.IndexOf(C)                                      
              orderby myobject.BelongCategoryName                                                                            
              select myobject;
```

Now the question is, I need to group this result by BelongCategoryName and concatenate output column for ItemName using add ","

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the requirement as follows:

```
var resultSet = 
       results.GroupBy(e => e.BelongCategoryName)
              .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, 
                  g => string.Join(",", g.Select(a => a.ItemName)));
```

`resultSet` is now a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

or if you want to chain the above query to the one you've already started:

```
var results = (from myobject in selectedItemList
               where myobject.ItemType == 5
               where myobject.BelongItemIndex == selectedItemList.IndexOf(C)
               orderby myobject.BelongCategoryName
               group myobject by myobject.BelongCategoryName)
               .ToDictionary(e => e.Key,
                      g => string.Join(",", g.Select(a => a.ItemName)));
```

or using query syntax only:

```
var results = from myobject in selectedItemList
              where myobject.ItemType == 5
              where myobject.BelongItemIndex == selectedItemList.IndexOf(C)
              orderby myobject.BelongCategoryName
              group myobject by myobject.BelongCategoryName into h
              select new
              {
                   BelongCategoryName = h.Key,
                   ItemNames = string.Join(", ", from e in h select e.ItemName)
              };
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
It's working fine.

Comment: @SithijaSahan you're welcome. I've also provided a query syntax only version if you're not a fan of the method syntax.

Comment: I need some little help, Meantime can i get summation of ItemPrice?
Thanks

Comment: @SithijaSahan sure... do you want a `Dictionary<string, int>` or an anonymous type with two properties of `BelongCategoryName` and sum of the price?

Comment: 2nd way is better, getting two properties, I checked you last code block, it's working fine and output is showing like "BelongCategoryName" & "ItemNames" i think it's better to have this type of output ,
Eg:

BelongCategoryName,ItemNames,TotalPrice

Like this

Comment: @SithijaSahan in that case simply change the `select` clause of the above query to `select new
                          {
                              BelongCategoryName = h.Key,
                              ItemNames = string.Join(", ", from e in h select e.ItemName),
                              TotalPrice = h.Sum(i => i.Price)
                          };`

Comment: I checked it, It's working fine.

Now my issue is OK,
I struggled with this issue for last 3hours, You solved it within few minutes
Thank you very much and i really appreciate it